# Are there 'cv' commands for these operations?

Tags: cv

Using `cv`, how can I can?

- rebuild triggers:
  `civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1`

and

- rebuild menu:
  `civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trigger rebuild

```
cv api4 System.flush triggers=1
```

Civi Menu rebuild and Cache clear

```
cv api4 System.flush
```

Comment: great! Thanks Pradeep. I had to write 'cv api4 System.flush triggers=1' and it's also a good learning to test API V4